# Issue with Popup

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a window.open() in a hyperlink to open a popup in my page. I have a folder structure like

```
  parent
     Controls
       Reports
        reportviewer.aspx
     Search.aspx
```

form search.aspx i need to open reportviewer.aspx in a popup(javascript) .How to achive this ?How to pass the url ?

Comment: you have to push your source code.

Answer (score 1):

In current situation the path could be
window.open("reportviewer.aspx")

but i think better way is to use ResolveUrl or ResolveClientUrl

Try something like that:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# string.Format("window.open(\"{0}\"); 
    return false;", ResolveUrl("~/AppFolder/YourPath/reportviewer.aspx"))%>' NavigateUrl="#" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:window.open('/reportviewer.aspx');");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both reportviewer.aspx and search.aspx are in the same folder,
the url can be passed as under 
    window.open('reportviewer.aspx');

Answer (score 0):

Take care of opening windows in pop-ups because some navigators are bloking popups. It causes me some explications about navigator's security to users.

I'm now using [NyroMal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/) it's a jquery plugin to make popups "in the page". No blocking..
there's some tutorials in the project's web site to learn how it is working..